# jQuery page refresh not reading or executing php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

sorry if the title is a little.. vague i couldnt pin it down.

So i am developing a friend request system which works i guess similar in concept to facebook. So you get a request and it lists them without a page reload.

However i get the div 'refreshing' or so i think i cant test the php which is where i have a problem, i will post the relevent code and files below.

It may look a little long winded but it shouldnt be too bad in reality. My php code should keep executing the query which is looking at the database in the updateFriendBox.php however it doesnt seem to be doing this. My code may be messy as well so I apologise.

myaccount.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function refreshDiv()
{
    $.get('updateFriendBox.php', function(data){$('#refresh').html(data);});
}
$(function()
{
    refreshDiv();
    setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
});


function box(x){
    if($('#'+x).is(":hidden")){
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
}
</script>

<?php
$addBox = '<div style="display:inline; padding:5px;">
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="javascript:box(\'fRequ\');">Show/Hide Friend Requests</a>
</div>';

// a bit further down in the code where its all called:

 <a href="#" class="tooltip"><? echo $addBox; ?></span></a>
          <div class="friendSlide" id="fRequ" style="height:240px; overflow:auto;">Your friend requests: <br />
          <div id="refresh"> <?php // this is where the refresh call is ?>
        </div>
        </center>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

updateFriendBox.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function acceptFriendRequest(x) {
    var url = "friendParse.php";
    $.post(url,{ request: "acceptFriend", reqID: x}, function(data){
        $("#req"+x).html(data).show().fadeOut(5000);
    });
}

function denyFriendRequest(x) {
    var url = "friendParse.php";
    $.post(url,{ request: "denyFriend", reqID: x}, function(data){
        $("#req"+x).html(data).show().fadeOut(5000);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
        <?php
        include 'dbc.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM friendRecu WHERE mem2='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
        $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($num_rows < 1) { 
            echo "No friend requests";
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $requestID = $row['id'];
                $req = $row['mem1'];
                $sqlName = mysql_query("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id='$req'");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName)){
                    $requesterName = $row['full_name'];
                }
                echo '<hr /><table width="100%", cellpadding="5"><tr><td width="17%" align="left"><div style="overflow:hidden; height:50px; color:white;"></div></td> <td width="83%"><a href=viewmembers.php?uid=' . $req . '">' . $requesterName . '</a> added you as a friend
                <span id="req' . $requestID . '">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:acceptFriendRequest(' . $requestID . ');">Accept</a>
                &nbsp; || &nbsp;
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:denyFriendRequest(' . $requestID . ');">Deny</a>
                </span></td></tr>
                </table>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Try using console for debugging js. Use this code and update us with your results: `$.get('updateFriendBox.php', function(data) {
  $('#refresh').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});`

Comment: Indeed, you need to either use firebug or some logging in order to find out what is going wrong, or at least get a bit more information about it.

Comment: It keeps poping up with "Load was performed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having a problem because your updateFriendBox.php is returning too much. Remove all that inline JS code, place it in an include file, and include it from myaccount.php. You also shouldn't have `<head> and <body>` sections in your updateFriendBox.php file.

The ajax call here doesn't create a whole new page, you're getting additional HTML to add to the *original* page.

So the only thing you should have there is your SQL query, the loop, and your HTML output for each data row.

Comment: One more thing, and this is more of a suggestion. Making your ajax call on a timer every 5 seconds isn't the best way to handle keeping that box updated. 5 seconds isn't enough to handle slow internet connections, and that's going to create a ton of traffic/load on your server. Maybe change it to once every minute, or better yet, look into something called long polling.

Comment: Hey, sorry to sound dumb (im new to this) but "inline js code" do you mean the accept and deny friend bit? Could you expand slightly on "You also should have and sections in your updateFriendBox.php file." thanks so much for taking time to help :-)

Comment: My bad, typo on the 'should have and sections', I've fixed it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by inline js code. The file you call to include with ajax should only be HTML. Those js functions can be included from the parent page.

Comment: Ahh right thanks, so now i have the separate file with those JS in with the extention .js (is that right?). I included it in the myaccount.php however rather than parsing it, it has just typed it out into the browser its self. I dont need any script tags or anything around an include do i?

Comment: Even more , you should pass ONLY data and do with it whatever you want (HTML , CSS , JS) in the calling page. Remeber - long response's content means more waiting time.

Comment: @OfirBaruch thanks! I will try strip it all out when it works :-)

Comment: Ahh, you did a PHP include? Just add this instead to your HTML in the `<head>`. `<script type="text/javascript" src="friendrequests.js"></script>`

Comment: @AndrewR that seemed to do the trick! Sorry too used to php haha! But it hasnt sorted the original problem. The friend request is in the database however its not showing on the page.

Comment: Im so sorry! I have just noticed the problem, i didnt start the session on the top of the page so it couldnt carry accross the $_SESSION. Thanks for all your input! I will mark you as answered correct because most likely if it wasn't for that it wouldnt work anyway! :-) thank you!